# Accessing methods across classes

Tags: c#, class

I want to be able to access methods in my "Uart" class from "AtCommand" class. i.e. the AT command class sends and receives commands to and from modem via serial port. I an unable to figure out why the methods in Uart are NOT available in "AtCommand" BUT they ARE available if I try to access them from my Main Form.

Here is the code for both classes, note: there are wriggly red lines under GsmPort.Write and warning it is not available in current context (so I assume scope issue).

```
using System.IO.Ports;
namespace ClassLessons
{
    class Uart
    {
        public bool Connected { get; set; }
        public bool DataInBuffer { get; set; }
        public string RxData;

    SerialPort port = new SerialPort();

    public Uart()
    {
        this.port.PortName = Properties.Settings.Default.PortName;
        this.DataInBuffer = false;
        this.RxData = "";
        this.port.BaudRate = 115200;
        this.port.ReadTimeout = 500;
        this.port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_DataReceived);
        Connected = false;
        try
        {
            if (!port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Open();
                Connected = true;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string data = this.port.ReadLine();
            RxData = data;
            DataInBuffer = true;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    public void Write(string message)
    {
        this.port.WriteLine(message);
    }


}
```

}
}

AND AtCommand :

```
namespace ClassLessons
{
    class AtCommand
    {
        Uart GsmPort = new Uart();
        GsmPort.Write("Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try declaring your class as `public class Uart { ...` and `GsmPort.Write("Test");` is not within a method, you can only call a method within a `method` or a `constructor`

Answer (score 1):

Your port field is private:

Change:

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
```

To:

```
public SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
```

And it will be publicly accessible in other classes.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `GsmPort.Write("Test")` outside of a method. You probably want something like:

```
namespace ClassLessons
{
    class AtCommand
    {
        Uart GsmPort = new Uart();
        public AtCommand()
        {
            GsmPort.Write("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make both your Uart and AtCommand **public** class